# How to show Form1 from Form2

Tags: forms

I want to close Form2 with a button(it belongs to Form2) also this button will show Form1.

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    Form1 form = new Form1();// It's wrong because we open a new object
    form.Show();
    this.Close();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to show Form 1 and close Form 2 you have to do:

IN FORM2:

```
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
```

IN FORM1:

```
    Form2 form2 = new Form 2(); //when you declare yur form 2
    form2.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(form2_FormClosed);

    void form2_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Visible = true;
    }
```